# Can you earn money at gun point in San Andreas?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

When you put gun on someone they put their hands up. Can you ask them to give you money?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't ***ask*** them for money.

However, if you point your gun long enough, they will eventually drop money on the ground. That is of course only assuming they *have* money to drop or are willing to drop it.

You'll need to kill them to find out if they were withholding their money or simply didn't have any.

Comment: But not everyone will do that right ?

Comment: @mjosh True, not everybody will drop their money. Some don't have money, and in the worst case scenario you can always kill them and loot their money.